# Why do my custom fonts reset and use the default font when I change my app theme to dark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, themes, flet

When im set my flet app to dark theme, my applied font change to default ?

Im try to set font after change theme but its usefull, and im use page.update() after change font or theme.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.